# ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line: 286

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a school project where I am using inheritance along with an Array List.  Both the Checking and Saving classes inherit from the Account class.  There is an additional Transaction class that is used to build an object for the Array List that is in both the Checking and Saving classes.  The project asks to open accounts with an opening balance.  Once done, one needs to be able to withdraw and deposit monies from these accounts.  Here is where the Array List comes into play.  One is to do the withdraw/deposit, and make an object from the Transaction class, then add it to the Array List.

This seems to be where my problem is at.  It seems that I am unable to make an object in my withdraw method in the Savings class.   When I print out what is in my Array List I get the following output.

> question8.TestClassAccount.Transaction@1bf8de1

Below is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class TestAccount {

public static void main(String[] args){

        int idNum = 0;
        double limit = 0, openBalSav = 0;
        String customer = "";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the customer's' name? ");
        customer = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the Account ID? ");
        idNum = input.nextInt();        
        System.out.println("How much are we putting in Savings? ");
        openBalSav = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the overdraft limit? ");
        limit = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
        Account accSav = new Savings(idNum, openBalSav, customer, limit);
        accSav.withdraw(100.00);
        accSav.withdraw(50.00);
        accSav.withdraw(75.00);
        accSav.printTransactions();

}

public class Savings extends Account {

private double overdraftLimit;
private double amount;
private char type;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private String description;
private ArrayList<Transaction> list = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

public Savings(){
    super();
    this.overdraftLimit = 0;
}
//Opening Account Constructor;
public Savings(int id, double balance, String customer,double             `enter code here`overdraftLimit){
    super(id, balance, customer);
    this.overdraftLimit = overdraftLimit;
}

public double withdraw(double amount){
    double newBalance = getBalance();
    newBalance -= amount;
    setBalance(newBalance); 
    Transaction item = new Transaction('w', amount, "withdraw");//break here
    list.add(item);
    return amount;
    }
}

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Transaction {

private Calendar dateCreated = Calendar.getInstance();
private char type;
private double amount;
private double balance;
private String description;
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
int year;
int month;
int day;
public Transaction(){
    this.type = 'w';
    this.amount = 0.00;
    this.balance = 0.00;
    this.description = "No description yet";
    this.dateCreated.getTime();
}

public Transaction(char type, double amount, String description){
    this.type = type;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post (add to you question by using [edit]) your entire exception with full Stack Trace and identify line# 286.

Comment: You don't seem to have any `class Account`.

Comment: It also looks like you forgot to close the `TestAccount` class.

Comment: TestAccount is at the top of my program list, and I will input my code for the account class below.  However, I think that my problem starts with this line of code.

Comment: Needed toString() method in my Transaction class.  Problem solved